# How to scan values in from keyboard- JAVA

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a code where the user enters to numbers, and the if statement compares the values to give an output. I feel the error is in how I am scanning the numbers. Any suggestions? (also sorry for the noob question, just starting to learn java)

```
public class MarvinsRoom {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Integer Value");
        firstNumber = scan.nextInt();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Integer Value");
        secondNumber = scan.nextInt();

        if (firstNumber > secondNumber) {
            System.out.println("Emotions");
        } else {
            System.out.println("no feelings");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Error: Two scan variables and variables firstNumber and secondNumber doesnt have types.

```
public class MarvinsRoom {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Integer Value");
        int firstNumber = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Integer Value");
        int secondNumber = scan.nextInt();

        if (firstNumber > secondNumber) {
            System.out.println("Emotions");
        } else {
            System.out.println("no feelings");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you imported Scanner?

Comment: As in `import java.util.Scanner;` before the `public class MarvinsRoom` .

Comment: You should include the entire program in your answer for someone who's beginning to learn as they may not use an IDE so they may not know where imports are required.

Comment: How do we know if he hadn't imported the necessary libraries?

Comment: Sometimes answers can be made better through comments.

Comment: Marking as correct or best answer will show some appreciation @Tushar Joshi

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is because you have two Scanner objects in your code, You only need one as it is in the same method. I think that should be the only issue you have as far as I can see

Answer (score -1):

Forgot to 
import java.util.Scanner;

and at the end

scan.close();

Comment: I posted that under my comment...did you appreciate that?